# angular guard with angular-redux/store

Tags: angular, redux, redux-observable, angular-router-guards, angular-redux

I'm using **@angular-redux/store** in my project.
I'm trying to create a guard with `@select()` decorator like this:

```
@select((s: IAppState) => s.user.userInformations.userState) userState$: Observable<number>;
```

**and my canActivate method is like this :**

```
canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userState$.pipe(map(value => {
      if (value === 0)
        return false;
      return true;
    }));
}
```

**What is the problem?**
the **userState$** always returns default value.(lets say undefined)

**What I tried so far?**
I tried to filter Observable like this:

```
this.userState$.pipe(skipWhile(val => val === undefined)).subscribe(value => {
  console.log('value', value);
});
```

it works fine and return value is what I expected (in constructor). but I can't use this in `canActivate` method. I don't know what is the best way to map data in `canActivate`.

Briefly: I'm looking for a way to skip first value of state (the initial value) and use it in `canActivate` method as an `Observable<boolean>`.

**P.S.** it would be better if I could config **@angular-redux/store** to skip undefiend/initialed value in @Select() decorator by default.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

We can use `Promise` to fix that. And since `Promise` doesn't return `Observable`, we should use `from` from rxjs.
the final code is like this:

```
  @select((s: IAppState) => s.user.userInformations.userState) userState$: Observable<number>;
  userStatePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.userState$.subscribe(val => {
      if (val !== undefined) {
        resolve(val)
      }
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })

  canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return from(this.userStatePromise).pipe(map(val => {
      if (val === 0) {
        // route anywhere you want
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }))

  }
```